# Toggle custom element in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a simple and pure javascript script that **toggle** a **custom** tag (like `<mytag>some text</my tag>`) in a contenteditable div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot outright *replace* an element's tag with JavaScript.

However, you *can* create an element on the fly, and set the contents of that element to be the original element.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('editable')[0];
e.onclick = function() {
  var d = document.createElement('textarea');
  d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
  e.parentNode.replaceChild(d, e);
}
```

```html
<div class="editable">Text</div>
```

As for toggling it, you'd need to set the element back to a `<div>`.

Hope this helps! :)